# Посчитать сумму элементов массива

Tags: php

Хочу написать на PHP функцию, которая может посчитать сумму элементов массива. Длина массива задается аргументом этой функции.

Пробовал написать, явно не то, help!

```
function get_sum($arr = 100) {
    $sum = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $arr[]; $i++) {
        echo $i;
    }
    $sum = $sum + $arr[$i];
    echo $sum;
}
```

Comment: arr.lenght ? не оно

Comment: так есть же `array_sum()`. Что еще надо?

Comment: Вы можете объяснить, что вы пытались сделать в вашей попытке?

Comment: Почему нужно передавать *длину* массива, а не сам массив? Есть массив – есть длина.

Comment: Готовая функция http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-sum.php Если хотите свою реализацию, выше примеры

Comment: а если нужно получить доступ к отдельным элеметам и сложить эти элементы , например есть трехмерный массив, нужно сложить 1x2 3x1 3x3
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не очень понял суть Вашего вопроса, но если Вы хотите написать функцию, которая считает сумму элементов массива, который передаётся в эту функцию, то надо сделать так:

```
function get_sum($arr) {
    $sum = 0;
    foreach($arr as $elem)
        $sum += $elem;
    return $sum;
}
```

Пример вызова функции:

```
$values = array(1,2,5,100,-30);
echo get_sum($values);            //выведет 78
```

Answer (score 4):

> Длина массива задается аргументом этой функции.

Эта фраза мне кажется неоднозначной. Имеется в виду, что единственный аргумент ф-ии – сам массив, и по нему определяем его длину? Или же ф-ии передаётся два параметра: сам массив и кол-во элементов, которое надо просуммировать, причём, это кол-во может быть меньше, равно, или даже больше, чем длина массива, и все эти случаи нужно обработать?

Ориентируюсь на самое простое объяснение, передаётся только сам массив.

```
function get_sum($arr) { // убрал значение по умолчанию (=100)
                         // – здесь ожидается массив, а не число

    $sum = 0;            // ок, инициализируем сумму
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) { // длина массива: count($arr)
        // перебираем элементы от 0 и до длина_минус_1:
        // напр. массив [0,1,2] а длина его 3. Поэтому верхнее значение
        // $i < 3

        $sum = $sum + $arr[$i]; // к общей сумме надо прибавить очередное значение из массива – внутри цикла, а не снаружи
    }
    return $sum; // есть смысл, чтобы ф-я возвращала результат,
                 // а что с ним делать дальше - выводить на экран или ещё что
                 // пусть решают там, снаружи ф-ии.
}

// теперь надо как-то использовать эту функцию:
echo "Сумма массива [1,2,3] = ";
echo get_sum( array(1,2,3) );
echo PHP_EOL; // символ новой строки
```

P.s. и если это не учебное задание, в PHP есть **встроенная функция**, которая суммирует все элементы данного массива быстрее, [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-sum.php):

```
echo "Сумма [1,2,3] = " . array_sum([1,2,3]) . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Написать сигнатуру метода, принимающего массив чисел
2. Объявить переменную для суммирования, значение `0`.
3. Пройти по массиву с помощью цикла for с индексом от нуля до длины массива, либо foreach
4. На каждой итерации прибавить к сумме i-й элемент. 
   После завершения цикла вернуть результат.

Answer (score 1):

Считаем сумму элементов массива $arr[] от 0 до $n, где $n - это параметр функции

```
function get_sum(array $arr, $n) {
$sum = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i <= $n; $i++) {
    $sum += $arr[$i];
}
return $sum;
```

}

$arr = [2, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5];
$n = 4;

echo get_sum($arr, $n); //выведет 21 сложило элементы с индексами от 0-го до 4-го

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function calculateSum($arr)
{
    if (empty($arr)) {
        return null;
    }
    $sum = 0;
    for ($sum as $num){
        $sum += $sum;

    }
    return $sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
$korzina = [100, 200, 600];
$sum = 0;
   for($i=0 ; $i <= count($korzina) ; $i++){
       $sum = $sum + $korzina[$i];
   };
echo $sum; // получим 900
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]